# Lifetime of WCF proxies

Tags: wcf, proxy, channel, lifetime, remoting

During migration of a set of old applications from Remoting to WCF I'm struggling with a good way of lifetime handling for the WCF proxies.

Initially I kept the same pattern I had with Remoting: Create a proxy server object during application startup and use it as long as the application is running.
This pattern had 2 problems, though:

- When any call during the runtime of the application failed and the server threw an exception, the client proxy would move to Faulted state and was no longer usable. I fixed this by adding an ErrorHandler on the server side and only throwing FaultExceptions.
- With infrequent server calls, the proxy channel would timeout after some time and you only notice when the next call fails. Increasing the Send/ReceiveTimeout to very long timespans is a no-go, from what I read.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441595/7220540) suggested creating a new proxy for every call and caching the ChannelFactory.

While this solved both problems, it also killed performance.
Caching the ChannelFactory was a good idea, but in contrast to what the article above said, creating the proxy is far from light-weight.
Well, creating the proxy itself is fast, but opening the Channel (what has to be done when calling the server) is incredible slow.

I've been using a plain vanilla net.tcp channel and each server call took about 2 seconds (in contrast to a few ms if re-using the proxy).

Because it's a large code base I don't want to go through each and every server call and check the lifetime requirements for each block of calls.

Now I'm unsure which way to go. Any advice?

Thanks in advance,
mav

Comment: In my opinion, you can set the channel time  longer to avoid channel expiration. We need to set receivetimeout and inactivitytimeout. I think you can also call the wcf service regularly to avoid channel expiration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Our customers tend to let the applications run for days without restart, so I'd have to set the timeout values very long. Without the lifetime management of SAO (server activated objects) the server has to keep the channel open  for very long, blocking ports and collecting more and more resources.

Implementing an additional hearbeat just to keep the channels from closing doesn't seem to be very straightforward, as well.

Comment: In my opinion, there is a solution to help you, you can re-create a new channel every time the client fails to call.